# error in "unpacking" nltk in python

Tags: python, error-handling, nltk

I'm repeatedly trying to install nltk to use in python. From a blank terminal (on a Mac), I start in a terminal shell and use the following command, which seems to install successfully

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -o - | python
```

Next, I command `sudo easy_install pip` and enter my password when prompted. Then I run `sudo pip install -U nltk` but get the following error

```
unknownb8e8560f309a:~ shannonmcgregor$ sudo pip install -U nltk
Downloading/unpacking nltk
Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement nltk
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for nltk
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/shannonmcgregor/.pip/pip.log"
```

What gives? can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you run **sudo pip install -U numpy**? Open the Python shell and write **import numpy** to test if this dependency is installed. Also, please let us know what version of Python you are running.

Comment: @ham-sandwich Hi! I have not imported numpy - should that be installed as part of the nltk process. Also, I am running Python 2.7.7

Answer (score 1):

**On second thoughts** - this looks like a problem with you pip or internet connection. First, make sure you have a solid internet connection.

try run the following command: `sudo -E pip install -U nltk`

`sudo -E` allows you to preserve your environment variables. I assume you are using some sort of proxy, or vpn.

---

**1st Assummption:** The installation process you are following does not include one of the (optional) dependencies which may or may not be the cause, Numpy. NLTK have specified that for Mac installation that you require the following steps:

1. Install Setuptools: `http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools`
2. Install Pip: run `sudo easy_install pip`
3. Install Numpy (optional): `run sudo pip install -U numpy`
4. Install NLTK: run `sudo pip install -U nltk`
5. Test installation: run python then type `import nltk`